# Emacs で、 CUI 上で notification がやりたい

Tags: emacs

特定の時間になったら、自分に通知をする機能を、 emacs で実現したいと思っています。

普段使っているのは、端末上で ssh した先にある emacs なので、 desktop-notification は使えないと思っています。

なので、通知としてはたとえば

- 画面上のカレントバッファが確認画面に切り替わる
- OK を押すと(ないしそれ相当のことをすると)このバッファは消える

のようなことができればいいなと考えています。

こういったようなことを実現するパッケージなどありますでしょうか。

Comment: デフォルトで `run-at-time` という関数がありますが、それで実現できるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[alert](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert) は、どうでしょう？ DBus も macOS も Buffer でも使えそうです。